# I need to generate numbers excluding specific ranges

Tags: python, numbers, generator

This is what I have tried:

```
import itertools
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 22, 23, 24]
comb = set(itertools.combinations(a, 3))
for x in comb:
     if (x == (range(1, 10), range(1, 10), range(1, 10))):
          continue
     print(x)
```

What I need this to do is to ignore the combinations of 3 numbers lower then 10.

Comment: You can at first filter your list if you need to exclude the number lower than 10. `a = [i for i in a if i >= 10]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is in the line:

```
if (x == (range(1, 10), range(1, 10), range(1, 10))):
```

Range is not a conditional in python. `range(1,10)` creates a sequence of numbers 1 to 10.

Instead we need to check if each element in our combination is less than 10. This could look like:

```
if (x[0]<10) and (x[1]<10) and (x[2]<10):
```

Furthermore, the code could then be optimized by just filtering `a` before running combinations on it, instead of having the for loop. But I will leave that to you.